# C - Linked List Segmentation Fault During Display

Tags: c, linked-list, segmentation-fault

Edit 2: I realized that I did not have a "Not found" result for any query not in the database. Changes have been made to introduce this feature. Here is the current test and test output:

Input:

```
3
sam
99912222
tom
11122222
harry
12299933
sam
edward
harry
```

Output:

```
Not found

=0
Not found

=0
Not found

=0
Not found

=0
sam
=99912222
Not found

=0
Not found

=0
Not found
[Infinite loop continues]
```

---

Edit: I have changed a few things in the while loop in display(). I am now getting an infinite loop printing "=0" except for the third or fourth cycle through the search. Hmmm...

By the way, thanks for the reminder of testing strings with `==`. Seems like a no-brainer now.

---

I have done some searching and have yet to be able to understand where I have gone wrong with my code. I am working on a challenge which will result in a simple phone-book program. It will take input of a number (the number of entries to be added) then the names and associated phone numbers (no dashes or periods). After the entries have been added then the user can search for entries by name and have the number displayed in the format "name=number".

The code throws a segmentation fault with the while loop in the display() function. I assume that I am attempting to print something assigned as NULL, but I cannot figure out where I have gone wrong. Any help would be very appreciated.

Lastly, the challenge calls for me to read queries until EOF; however, this confuses me since I am to accept user input from stdin. What does EOF look like with stdin, just a register return (`\n`)?

(PS: This is my first attempt at linked lists, so any pointers would be greatly appreciated.)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void add_entry(void);
void display(void);

struct phonebook {
        char name[50];
        int number;
        struct phonebook *next;
    };
    struct phonebook *firstp, *currentp, *newp;
    char tempname[50];

int main() {
    int N;
    firstp = NULL;
    scanf("%d", &N);
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        add_entry();
    }
    display();

    return 0;
}

void add_entry(void) {
    newp = (struct phonebook*)malloc(sizeof(struct phonebook));
    if (firstp == NULL) firstp = currentp = newp;
    else {
        currentp = firstp;
        while (currentp->next != NULL)
            currentp = currentp->next;
        currentp->next = newp;
        currentp = newp;
    }
    fgets(currentp->name, 50, stdin);
    scanf("%d", &currentp->number);

    currentp->next = NULL;
}

void display(void) {
    while (strcmp(tempname, "\n") != 0) {
        currentp = firstp;
        fgets(tempname, 50, stdin);

        while (strcmp(currentp->name, tempname) != 0) {
            if (currentp->next == NULL) {
                printf("Not found\n");
                break;
            }
            currentp = currentp->next;
        }
        printf("%s=%d\n", currentp->name, currentp->number);
    }
}
```

Comment: Here is a pointer : `int n = 0; int *pointer = &n;`. I'm always glad to help :)

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you never find the entry you're looking for. The expression `currentp->name != tempname` will always be true, since those are always unequal. In C, this equality test will not compile into a character-by-character comparison, but into a comparison of pointers to `currentp->name` and `tempname`. Since those are never at the same addresses, they will never be equal.

Try `!strcmp(currentp->name, tempname)` instead.

The reason you crash, then, is because you reach the end of the list, so that `currentp` will be `NULL` after your loop, and then you try to print `NULL->name` and `NULL->number`, actually causing the crash.

Also, on another note, you may want to start using local variables instead of using global variables for everything.

Comment: Thank you. I have made the changes. Is it possible that the infinite loop is due to the presence of a newline character at the end of tempname?

Comment: @JoeyGrant: Since you're using the same method to input the names in the list as the tempname, it seems the newline should be either present or missing in both, so that doesn't sound like it should be a problem.

Comment: @JoeyGrant: However, you have to check `strcmp(...) == 0`, not `!= 0`. `strcmp()` returns zero when the strings are equal.

Comment: But while it is not equal, I need to move to the next structure in the linked list, correct?

Comment: @JoeyGrant: You do indeed.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this solves the problem, but you can't directly compare strings with != in C. You need to use if( strcmp( string1, string2 ) == 0 ) to check.

fgets doesn't take EOF (= -1) like getchar does, but it does include '\n' and pad the rest with NULL (= 0) so checking for EOF is not really helpful, but yes you can stop after \n or NULL.

Comment: This definitely helps out. I have edited the problem at hand. Now I am getting an infinite loop and only 1 correct display 3 cycles in.

Comment: Are you talking about: while (strcmp(tempname, "\n") != 0)? This doesn't work the way you intend it to and it will always be infinite unless you have an entry that is a string composed ONLY of '\n'. You don't need that loop at all. strcmp parses two strings (just arrays of chars) in a parallel manner and tests if all the characters are equivalent (in which case it returns 0, or else returns an int signifying the difference).
What were you originally trying to do with this line?

Comment: I need the program to continue accepting search queries until (what the program challenge describes) EOF. I assumed that this would mean that I would receive an empty string for the termination of such loop. However, this is obviously wrong due to the continued presence of the infinite output loop. Thoughts on an alternative?

Comment: Oh, right. Sorry, fgets *does* take EOF too, it just also takes \n which is what it usually uses to know when input has finished. In that case maybe put the while loop != EOF right after fgets(tempname,...). You should take care to put the while loop *after* reading the input value of tempname. Like said below, you shouldn't be using global variables here - they're a bad idea just in general because it's hard to keep track of them, and its how you ended up putting that loop in the wrong place...